# Can't convert .py files into .exe files

Tags: python

I want to turn python files into .exe files but I can't. I have installed py2exe
when I run the program setup.py on the windows command prompt with that command line

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

I get the following error message:

```
no module named py2exe
```

Comment: Is py2exe in your PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 4):

To quote the [py2exe tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial):

> "py2exe" is a new Distutils command that is added when you import
>   py2exe. To use py2exe you need to create a setup.py file to tell
>   Distutils and py2exe what you want to do. Here's a setup.py whose
>   simplicity is appropriate for our sample program...

So their example setup.py script is:

```
     from distutils.core import setup
     import py2exe
     setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

Which can be built with

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

So I think you are just missing the import.  Post your full setup.py if this is not the case so we can debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I found a video tutorial. I managed to run the script from the command prompt

Comment: if you are happy with an answer its good practice to accept it by clicking the tick mark :)

Comment: Just one Question here - if `hello.py` has been converted to `hello.exe` would be able to run on machine where `python` not installed?

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU if I remember correctly, py2exe has options to tell it whether you want to include the interpreter in the final exe file or not.

Comment: Can I have a bit help on that to make `.exe` file from `.py` file, which can run on any windows machine without `python` installation?